# output step_lencode_mixed (from R package embed)

Tags: r, embed, tidymodels

I have three questions about the sample code below which illustrates the use of `step_lencode_mixed`.

I read in the [vignette](https://embed.tidymodels.org/reference/step_lencode_mixed.html) that: "For each factor predictor, a generalized linear model is fit to the outcome and the coefficients are returned as the encoding."

In the output from the example below the column 'partial' is the return from `step_lencode_mixed`. My questions:

1. Should I use this **partial** as encoded catagorical variabele "where_town" in the new model to be fitted?
2. Is there a complete model (Class ~ ., data = okc_train) with all variables on Class fitted in the background and is the contribution from variabele "where_town" returned as **partial**?
3. If I convert the partial with the logit2prob function, I notice that the outcome is almost identical to the rate. For that reason I suppose the outcome is not a coefficient?

Thanks a lot!

```
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Feature Engineering and Selection: A Practical Approach for Predictive Models
# by Max Kuhn and Kjell Johnson
#
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# 
# Code for Section 5.4 at
# https://bookdown.org/max/FES/categorical-supervised-encoding.html
#
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# 
# Code requires these packages: 

library(tidymodels)
library(embed)

# Create example data ----------------------------------------------------------

load("../Data_Sets/OkCupid/okc.RData")
load("../Data_Sets/OkCupid/okc_binary.RData")

options(width = 120)

    partial_rec <- 
      recipe(Class ~ ., data = okc_train) %>%
      step_lencode_mixed(
        where_town,
        outcome = vars(Class)
      ) %>%
      prep()

    okc_train2 <- okc_train %>% select(where_town, Class)

    partial_rec2 <- 
       recipe(Class ~ ., data = okc_train2) %>%
       step_lencode_mixed(
         where_town,
         outcome = vars(Class)
       ) %>%
       prep()

    
    
    # Organize results -------------------------------------------------------------
    
    partial_pooled <- 
      tidy(partial_rec, number = 1) %>%
      dplyr::select(-terms, -id) %>%
      setNames(c("where_town", "partial"))
    
    partial_pooled <- left_join(partial_pooled, okc_props)
    
    partial_pooled2 <- 
      tidy(partial_rec2, number = 1) %>%
      dplyr::select(-terms, -id) %>%
      setNames(c("where_town", "partial"))

    all.equal(partial_pooled, partial_pooled2)
>
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I use this partial as encoded catagorical variabele "where_town" in the new model to be fitted?

Yes. You don't have to do it manually though. The [`bake()` function](https://www.tmwr.org/dimensionality.html#recipe-functions) does that for you automatically (same as if you [include the recipe in a workflow](https://www.tmwr.org/recipes.html#using-recipes))

> Is there a complete model (Class ~ ., data = okc_train) with all variables on Class fitted in the background and is the contribution from variable "where_town" returned as `partial`?

Yes. There is more information in the [tidymodels book](https://www.tmwr.org/categorical.html#using-the-outcome-for-encoding-predictors) (section 17.3).

> If I convert the partial with the logit2prob function, I notice that the outcome is almost identical to the rate. For that reason, I suppose the outcome is not a coefficient?

A simpler method to do the conversion to the rate is `binomial()$linkinv(partial_pooled$partial)`.

The value given in the `partial` column is the log-odds value (hence the negative numbers); we use logistic regression (mixed model) to estimate. It uses an empirical Bayes estimation method that shrinks the coefficient estimates toward the overall (population) estimate.

The amount of shrinkage, for this model, is based on a few things but is mostly driven by the per-category sample size. Smaller sample sizes are affected more than categories with larger amounts of data. So the raw and shrunken estimates for `berkeley` are about the same since there were 2676 data points there but `belvedere_tiburon` has larger differences in estimates because the sample size was 35.

Comment: @ topepo Thank you for your time! Your anwer to my question 2 is yes. Although after I have added okc_train2 to the code above for which all variables are dropped from okc_train except 'where_town' and target 'Class', the outcomes for partial_pooled2 are exactly the same as for partial_pooled! Is this not very unexpected in case a complete model with all variables is fitted in the background and only the contribution from 'where_town' is returned? I would expect a smaller contribution in partial_pooled compared to partial_pooled2 due to the contribution of the other variables.